# ScriptManager.SetFocus not working

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have quite a complex page that has some AJAX functionality.  The structure of the page consists of a `<asp:ScriptManager>` in the aspx page & 3 user controls.

One of the user controls in the page links to another user control.

The second level user control contains a number of `<asp:UpdatePanel>` controls.  Inside the update panel I'm using a `<asp:RadioButtonList>` control set to `AutoPostBack="True"` and in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event I'm using `ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SetFocus(txtAddressLine1);` to try and set the focus to a text box when the radio button list has a particular selected value.

The focus is currently not being set but when debugging the code to set the focus is being executed.

I created a simple example page with this structure (aspx -> user control -> nested user control with UpdatePanel) and focus is being set correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be causing the focus not to be set?

I'm using Windows 7 with IIS, Visual Studio 2010 Professional, .NET 4.0, C# and the web.config does not have anything set for the `<xhtmlConformance>` property.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors on the client side?

Comment: There are no javascript errors on the client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the following code in the user control:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtQNumber != null) txtQNumber.Focus(); 
}
```

The focus was being set to another text field overriding the `ScriptManager.SetFocus()`.